# length of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The length of a module $M$ is defined as the supremum of all $l$ in $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\} $ such that there is a chain of submodules $0\subsetneq M_1\subsetneq M_2\subsetneq...\subsetneq M_l=M$.

Why is the length of $\mathbb{Z}$ equals to $\infty$?

Since we have $(n)\subsetneq(m)\Leftrightarrow m|n, m\neq n$, there couldn't be such an infinite chain.

Comment: But it has arbitrarily long finite chains.

Comment: You can show that each element of $\mathbb{N}$ is the length of some chain. The supremum of $\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ is $\infty$. The length of $\mathbb{Z}$ is therefore $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is not that any *single* chain is necessarily infinite, but rather that you can construct chains of varying lengths. Note the word *supremum* in your definition. Consider elements of the form $m^n$ and the chains generated by them (i.e. $m^n\Bbb Z$).

Comment: So I have shown that there is not directly a chain that shows that $\mathbb{Z}$ has infinite length?

Comment: Correct. No single chain does, but you can make longer and longer ones no problem.